# Как сделать ссылку которая переносит пользователя в определённое место уже открытой страницы?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть ссылки которые переносят пользователя на другую страницу, а есть такие, что переносят пользователя в определенное место уже открытой страницы. К примеру они используются в содержании к сайту. Как сделать такую ссылку? Если это сложная тема можно не описывать её здесь, а просто скинуть ссылку на урок.

Answer (score 1):

Если не отправлять на просторы Интернет, тогда все просто: `<a href="#anchor">ссылка</a>` и `id="anchor"` элементу к которому нужно отправиться.

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#anchor">ссылка</a>
<div></div>
<span id="anchor">мне сюда</span>
<div></div>
```